# On open subset of a closed subscheme of an irreducible scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible projective scheme (over $\mathbb C$) and $Y$ be a closed subscheme of $X$. Let $U$ be a non-empty open in $Y$ such that $Y=U \cup V$ is a disjoint union with $V$ a closed subscheme in $Y$.

Since as a topological space one can write $U:= W \cap Y$ for some non-empty open $W \subset X$.

Can we use irreducibility of $X$ to conclude that $U$ is dense in $Y$?

If this is not true in general, then can we impose some conditions on $U, Y$ so that this is true? (e.g. can we say something when $Y$ and $V \subset Y$ are both determinantal variety?)

Any hint, suggestion is appreciated

Comment: In general $Y$ need not be irreducible or even connected. For example, $Y$ could be a finite union of at least $2$ points. Then if $U$ is a single point, it is not dense in $Y$. So your question is really: Is $Y$ irreducible?

Comment: @red_trumpet, my question is even if $Y$ is not irreducible, can we impose some condition on $U$ such that that specific $U$ is dense in $Y$ (under the assumption that both $Y$ and $V$ are determinantal)?